# Using a delimited string, how do I get an array item?

Tags: php, arrays

Here's an array:

```
array('csv'=>
      array('path'=>'/file.csv',
            'lines'=>array('line1',
                           'line2',
                           'line3'
                          )
      )
)
```

As you can see, the array goes three levels deep.

Here are two strings:

```
1. 'csv/path'
2. 'csv/lines/0
```

Using `/` as the delimiter, string 1 will get `'/file.csv'` and string 2 will get `'line1'`. I've been thinking about using a recursive function, but I just don't know yet how to go about it.

The idea is I won't know which array key I'm accessing. I'm working on creating a generic function that will take a string as input and return the respective value in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](https://eval.in/156443)

Just iterate through each key from the string given, setting the new array to pull from as the found element in the given array. You should add error handling.

```
<?php

$array = array('csv'=>
      array('path'=>'/file.csv',
            'lines'=>array('line1',
                           'line2',
                           'line3'
                          )
      )
);

echo extractData($array, 'csv/path'); // echoes /file.csv

echo extractData($array, 'csv/lines/0'); // echoes line1

function extractData($array, $string){
  $keys = explode('/', $string);
  $data = $array;
  foreach ($keys as $key){
    $data = $data[$key];
  }
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: It works fine. Now I'm just working on a way to return the original value as a reference so that I can change the value in the array as needed.

Comment: You can do that by returning an array `return array($string, $array);`  but it makes no sense, you have the string there when you call the function.

Comment: Well maybe I want to modify the path. I'd like to say `$tmp =& extractData($array, 'csv/path');` So that I can say `$tmp = '/new-file.csv` to set the new file in the `$array` variable. So far extractData returns a value instead of a reference in `$array`.

Comment: It returns a value because you're giving it a reference and the source array. Ah so you want to use it to update the array too. Makes sense. Are you asking me to do that for you?

Comment: Now I'm just reaching out for helpful tips, advice and solutions. That would be helpful since I've been thinking about how to make it happen and have not come up with solutions. I've processed it in my mind many different ways. The solution I'm thinking about is ideal: to return a reference to the array item given the / delimited string.

Comment: It's simple, add another argument `extractData($array, $string, $new = NULL)` which is by default NULL (you may want to set something to false). The function already finds `$data[$key];`. `if ($set !== NULL) $data[$key] = $set;`

Comment: "The solution I'm thinking about is ideal: to return a reference to the array item given the / delimited string" - that's the string you started out with! There is no other magic pointer to that variable in that array. You've created that with this function.

Comment: When it says `$data = $array` and then returning `$data`, it's returning the value instead of the reference to `$array['csv']['path']`.

Comment: The reference to `$array['csv']['path']` is, in your terms, `'csv/path'`. It returns the value because that's what you asked for. There is no other magic pointer that will get you to that element in that array. Do you want it to return the string `"$array['csv']['path']"`?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the reference to"

Comment: When I call the `extractData` function, it will return the value perfectly. But I cannot modify that particular value in the array. What I mean is, at least fundamentally, we could create a function to call `setData('csv/path', $value)` and have it set `$array['csv']['path']` to `$value`.

Comment: I told you how to do that using the same function 42 minutes ago.

Comment: It seems to only set the 1-dimensional array (`$data[$key]`). It seems I might be missing something because I need to be able to set `$data['csv']['path']`, for example, when given `csv/path` as the argument. So I can say `$path =& extractData($array, 'csv/path')` and then set `$path = '/new-file.csv'` to set `$array['csv']['path'] = '/new-file.csv'`. The function definition, therefore, would be `function &extractData($array, $str){}`.

Comment: Ah I may be misled you, setting $data[$key] won't change the array, it needs to be `$array` that you set. Ok, you only need one function. Let's rename it. `getOrSetData($array, $pointer, $value = NULL);` where $array is the array, $pointer is the string e.g. 'csv/path' and $value is the new value IF you want to set not get. You will need to `explode` the pointer to get each key and set `$array[$keys[0]][$key[1]][...]`. How to construct that line is a different question. You could easily use `eval()`.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been thinking: to set $array[$key[0]][$key[1]] to a desired value, but I haven't yet understood how to get there. Creating a string "[$key[0]][$key[1]]" I've looked at briefly but didn't know how to get the array index. The `eval()` function seems to be a viable solution. It might not be the best solution but could possibly work for my needs.

Comment: The & (ampersand) symbol shows the function returns a reference to the variable. So `&function getPath(){return $_SESSION['csv']['path'];}` will return a reference to `$_SESSION['csv']['path']`.